# Security of hardcoded URL in Android application

Tags: android, security, url

My application connects with a server by URL which is included in an application code. From security point of view, hardcoding such as URL is not a good practice (e.g. due to possibility of reverse engineering). How this could be improve? How improve security of URL?

Comment: "hardcoding such as URL is not a good practice" -- why? URLs are routinely visible in Web apps and Web sites, such as this one.

Comment: But when you publish application, for example in Google Play, everybody can find data about the server (URL) with which application tries to connect. I think it is not a good practice to reveal such data directly

Comment: What's so sensitive about that URL?

Comment: "everybody can find data about the server (URL) with which application tries to connect" -- sure. This is no different than with a Web app.

Comment: So according to you there is nothing wrong with hardcoding URL?

Comment: Even if you use some kind of protection to hide URL anyone can use Wireshark on network that your app is using and find out your URL. URL is public and there is nothing to hide about it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to because URLs are supposed to be public. Even if you hide it in app anyone can sniff network for traffic and see your apps traffic and read your URL from HTTP/HTTPS packets.

Think of an Android app as a website/webapp. Why would you hide URL from your website?